# longtable and floatrow: font commands ignored

Tags: fonts, floats, longtable, floatrow, ltxtable

If I load both `longtable` (`ltxtable`) and `floatrow`, then `\sffamily` is ignored and the table is typeset in roman. If I disable `floatrow` everything works as expected. 
`floatrow`s `\RawFloats` command does not work here as a solution. I had only error messages when I inserted it.

Here is the example code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ltxtable} %
\usepackage{filecontents} %
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{caption} %

\listfiles

\begin{document}

% Creation of the table in a separate file
\begin{filecontents}{content/longtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{>{\itshape}l*{2}{X}}
\captionabove{longtable tabular with tabularx columns} \\
  \hline
  title & title \\ \hline
\endhead
  \hline
\endlastfoot
description   & content & \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

% Loading of the table from the separate file
{
  \small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\sffamily
  \LTXtable{\textwidth}{content/longtable.tex}
}
\end{document}
```

Which results in the following

[image]

Any idea how to get the sans serif font in the table back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `floatrow` package controls the font of float object contents and also of `longtable`s, so you'll have to add `\floatsetup[table]{font=sf}` to your preamble (and may remove `\sffamily` from the redefinition of `\arraystretch`). See section 3.1.2 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{ltxtable} %
\usepackage{filecontents} %
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{font=sf}
\usepackage{caption} %

\listfiles

\begin{document}

% Creation of the table in a separate file
\begin{filecontents}{longtable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{>{\itshape}l*{2}{X}}
\captionabove{longtable tabular with tabularx columns} \\
  \hline
  title & title \\ \hline
\endhead
  \hline
\endlastfoot
description   & content & \\
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents}

% Loading of the table from the separate file
{
  \small\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \LTXtable{\textwidth}{longtable.tex}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Should you also want to change the caption fonts, use the `\captionsetup` macro provided by the `caption` package:

```
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=sf,font=sf}
```

[image]

Comment: It works that way - but I wonder if this was a good design decisions. I think of floatrow as a caption and figure/tabular alignment tool that provides float extension. And it can causes problems in normal latex code if the floatrow extensions are not used...